# active record not retrieving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

been trying to pull products from category but its not worki. from the rails console when i enter

`category = Category.where(id: 1)`

will return the category but when i type

`category.products`

returns back

```
`NoMethodError: undefined method `products' for #<Category::ActiveRecord_Relation`
```

but when i type

`category = Category.first`

then do

`category.products`

i get all the products belonging to that category. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`where` returns a collection, while `first` returns a Category as the error says.

If you do `Category.find(1)` instead of where it will work.

Comment: how can i use this in my controller to retrieve the products

Comment: `category = Category.find(1)` then `category.products` but if you're not doing anything with the category you might want to do `products = Product.joins(:category).where(categories: { id: 1 })`

Comment: well categories will be added dynamically. so lets say on the show controller how can i use something like this `    @categories = Category.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I would name your variable `@category` as you only have one, and you can simply then do `@category.products`

Comment: when i call it his way i cannot run  category.product.each

Comment: What do you mean?  Is that a typo?  You can do `@category.products.each do |product|`....e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

The first query gives you a collection of categories where it's `id` matches `1`. Because only one record can possibly match this query, there is only one object in the collection. You cannot call `products`on the collection directly however.

The second query gives you the first category object found in the database using the default sort order. As it is an active record instance instead of relation (collection), you can call products on it.

To get only a single object by id, use `find_by(id: 1)` or simply `find(1)`.

Do read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html thoroughly for more details.

Comment: so if i watn to find a catefory in my show controller then loop through that category to get the products what should i do?